# Create RuntimeEnvironment from Remote .jar

Tags: java, jbpm, kie, runtime-environment

Im trying to run Jbpm Project, using de .jar file created in a remote Server.

In my old project i created my RuntimeEnvironment with a .bpmn file...

```
    @Produces
    @Singleton
    @PerProcessInstance
    @PerRequest
    public RuntimeEnvironment produceEnvironment(EntityManagerFactory emf) throws IOException {
        RuntimeEnvironment environment = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
                .newDefaultBuilder()
                .entityManagerFactory(emf)
                .addAsset(
                        ResourceFactory
                                .newClassPathResource("rewards-basic.bpmn"),
                        ResourceType.BPMN2).get();
        return environment;
    }
```

It works fine.

But now i want to use a .jar that is in a remote Repository.
Example:

```
   @Produces
    @Singleton
    @PerProcessInstance
    @PerRequest
    public RuntimeEnvironment produceEnvironment(EntityManagerFactory emf) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://server:8080/jbpm-console/maven2/group/testHtmlForms/1.0/testHtmlForms-1.0.jar";
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
        UrlResource urlResource = (UrlResource) ks.getResources()
                .newUrlResource(url);
        urlResource.setUsername("admin");
        urlResource.setPassword("admin");
        urlResource.setBasicAuthentication("enabled");
        InputStream is = urlResource.getInputStream();
        KieModule kModule = kr.addKieModule(ks.getResources()
                .newInputStreamResource(is));
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kModule.getReleaseId());

        RuntimeEnvironment environment = ????????
        return environment;
    }
```

That is Possible?? How I create the RuntimeEnvironment??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how to create a ksession from a jar on a maven repo:

https://github.com/krisv/jbpm-evaluation-examples/blob/master/kjar-from-guvnor/src/main/java/org/jbpm/evaluation/EvaluationExampleKJarFromGuvnor.java

Comment: New Exception:

Exception in thread "FileRepositoryConnector-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: number of transferred bytes cannot be negative.


Any Idea?